# How to determine what in my script is blocking my HTML rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, rendering, blocking

I have a web application that uses quite a bit of JavaScript.

When the page loads, it's very clear visually that something is blocking the rendering of a particular portion of the web site. This portion is generated by a Tabber Tabify JavaScript library.

How can I determine what's blocking the HTML rendering specifically so that I can modify my code to prevent this blocking?

Can I use Firebug, or some other tool, to walk through my HTML/JavaScript to determine where the HTML rendering is being blocked and if so, how?

**UPDATE**:

YSlow gives my web-application a score of "A" and Page Speed give a score of 94/100.

**UPDATE 2:**

The live site is linked below.

[http://www.elite.com](http://www.elite.com/)

What I'm specifically referring too is the actual Tabs themselves being rendering (and NOT the panel content inside the tab panes). It seems strange to me that the Tab headings themselves are taking so long to generate on the first (empty cache) page load.

Comment: @vicki Firebug is useful for breakpoint in HTML document

Comment: @4th page, so if I set breakpoints - you're saying that will somehow help me determine what's blocking my HTML rendering?

Comment: why not! we can easily find out problem and solve it using Firebug especially in JS and css

Comment: @4th page, do you know of any good tutorial to show me how to do this?

Comment: Vicki, I checked out the live site and nothing about it seems slow to me.

Comment: I also checked the site, and did not see a particularly bad lag in rendering. There is a small noticeable one, but pretty much all the JS UI libraries need some time to render widgets and whatnot. On small pages it appears  to be instant, but if you're doing a lot it's hard to avoid some slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities:

1. Loading scripts in your page will block rendering (the only fix for this is to put them in the head (blocks initial rendering) or at the end just before the `</body>` or load them after the page is loaded (e.g. onload)
2. Whatever the Tabber/Tabify tool is, needs time to process content... see if there is a way to optimize it.

Either way, if you post some code we can likely be of more help

**Update:**

If I load the page with my cache cleared, I see content rendering on the screen, then hiding (as it becomes hidden tab content)

Changing the non-visible content to `display:none;` when loading, and then only setting it back to `display:block;` once the Tabify stuff is done might help (a) speed up the rendering and (b) remove any flash of content that later gets hidden.

The RadComboBox'es you have load inline (which means the scripts block rendering)... if you can delay this until the onload event fires it will speed up rendering.

I would move the Unica Page Tag (tracking) to the end of your page too.

You have 8 external script files - if there is any way you can combine them it would be good.

You don't have gzip turned on for most of those script files

All of your static content (images, css, scripts) don't have an expires header which means they won't get cached, which means pages won't load fast after the first page.

Comment: @scunliffe, I've included the link in my original post above

Comment: @scunliffe, did the link above help?

Comment: @Vicki - it is, I'll be running through it when I get a chance